# How to remove the extra record from table in sql

Tags: sql

I have one table log:

```
checktype
---------
    I
    O
    I
    o
    I
    I
    I
    o
    I
    O
```

Now I want that **I** and **O** should be in a pair so I want to delete the extra **I**, means I want only one **(I or O)** after each other.
The table should contain only **I** and **O** in pairs.

Comment: And how do you distinguish the individual rows? With the given sample data it's impossible to delete them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well, I can see one way of deleting a few rows and the remaining rows be in pairs :)

Comment: What database you are using?

Comment: SQL tables are *sets* and inherently unordered.  How do you specify the ordering of the values?  How do you identify a given row?

Comment: You can test my code. But my question is how can you distinguish the particular CheckID to be deleted?

Answer (score 2):

You can get this result with the following query quite easily.

```
Select checktype,((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY checktype))*2 - 1) as Row_id From Table
Where checktype = 'I' 
UNION
Select checktype,((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY checktype))*2 ) as Row_id From Table
Where checktype = 'O' 
Order by Row_id
```

I have tested it and it is working for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT checkType FROM myTable");
while(rs.next( )){
   if (rs.getString("checkType").equals('I'){
       if(rs.next(){
          if(rs.getString("checkType").equals('O'){
          }else{
           //delete logic  
          }           
       }
   } else if(rs.getString("checkType").equals('O'){
       if(rs.next(){
          if(rs.getString("checkType").equals('I'){
          }else{
           //delete logic  
          }           
       }
   }
}
```